# Oracle - Unix query

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I just want to write the query output in a .txt file using Unix shell script. Below is my code:

```
SET PAGESIZE 20000
SET COLSEP ","
SET LINESIZE 385
SET NUMWIDTH 300
SET WRAP OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET UNDERLINE OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL OFF
SET TAB OFF

COLUMN NSC Format a8
COLUMN STATUS Format a6
COLUMN GEO_CD Format a6
COLUMN COUNTRY Format a7
COLUMN LATA Format a4
COLUMN COMMUNITY_NAME a14
COLUMN COUNTY a6
COLUMN STREET_NUM1 a11
COLUMN POSTAL_CD a9

SPOOL NRM1.txt

SELECT GEO_SITE_CD||GEOP_SITE_CD||NW_SITE_CD NSC,STUS_CD STATUS,GEOP_SITE_CD GEO_CD,CTRY_CD COUNTRY,GEO_LATA_CD LATA,NVL(CURR_GEO_SITE_NME,GEO_SITE_NME) COMMUNITY_NAME,
CNTY_NME COUNTY,'"'||RPAD(NVL(TRIM(ADR_STREET_NBR),'                '),15,' ')||'"' STREET_NUM1,
PSTL_CD POSTAL_CD
FROM CLONE_NW_SITE
WHERE CTRY_CD IN ('USA','PRI','VRI')
AND ROWNUM < 100
ORDER BY NSC;

SPOOL OFF
```

Output looks below:

```
NSC     ,STATUS,GEO_CD,COUNTRY,LATA,COMMUNITY_NAME                                              ,COUNTY                                       ,STREET_NUM1                                                   ,POSTAL_CD                      
ABITPR01,A     ,PR    ,PRI    ,    ,AIBONITO (AIBONITO)                                         ,AIBONITO                                     ,"               "                                             ,00705
```

Required Output looks below:

```
NSC     ,STATUS,GEO_CD,COUNTRY,LATA,COMMUNITY_NAME                                              ,COUNTY                                       ,STREET_NUM1,POSTAL_CD                      
ABITPR01,A     ,PR    ,PRI    ,    ,AIBONITO (AIBONITO)                                         ,AIBONITO                                     ,"               ",00705
```

For STREET_NUM1 - I used RPAD / NVL, it changes the header size and after the values " " - it has 45 extra spaces. I don't want those.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code given in this question is *not* a UNIX shell script. It's not clear to me what this question has to do with UNIX at all.

Comment: Which version of Oracle / sqlplus is this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like value already present in `ADR_STREET_NBR` column is more than your desired length, which is causing this problem. Use `SUBSTR` function after `RPAD` and it should solve your issue.

Another comment is , in `NVL` use `''` instead of `'         '`. `RPAD` will take care of padding spaces when you do not have value.